# YQL query failing

Tags: sql, api, yahoo, yql, yahoo-api

I am executing the follwing YQL on fantasysports table.

> select * from fantasysports.games where use_login=1 and game_key in ('238', '223', 'mlb', 'nfl')

But it is failing by giving the following response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng"
yahoo:count="0" yahoo:created="2014-08-05T05:47:43Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
<diagnostics>
    <publiclyCallable>true</publiclyCallable>
    <url execution-start-time="1" execution-stop-time="520"
        execution-time="519" http-status-code="500" http-status-message="INKApi Error">
    <![CDATA[http://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/users;use_login=1/games;game_keys=238,223,mlb,nfl]]></url>
    <user-time>520</user-time>
    <service-time>519</service-time>
    <build-version>0.2.2666</build-version>
</diagnostics> 
<results/>
```

**Queries executed on other tables are working fine.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug on the Yahoo side of things. It's been [logged on the YQL Forum](https://developer.yahoo.com/forum/YQL/Fantasy-Sports-YQL-Console-returning-INKApi/1399927585884-7008ef4d-0696-4114-b789-1840b0f798ff) and the last update was a developer 5 days ago (31st July 2014) saying it was being looked into